# Where can I confirm that my HTC One XL is evita model?

Tags: settings, htc-one-xl

I want to double check that my HTC One XL is evita model.

I am almost sure I saw it in a menu somewhere but I cannot find it anymore.

Could somebody guide me where I can find such info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_One_X#Model_comparison_table), all the HTC One XL devices fall under the Evita model. Evita is just the code name for the device. Just about every device is initially manufactured with a "codename". This is more just like an internal name for the device. This could be because they have not decided on a "public brand" for the device yet, or just because they want to call it something else internally.

Sometimes the codename resides in the model name in the Settings -> About Phone. But if you have `adb` access to your device, you can do something like:

```
> adb shell
$ getprop
```

this will dump out all the properties that are configured during the boot process. one of them, probably something like `ro.product.device` will contain the value `evita`.

Comment: It was `ro.product.name`. Great explanation and how-to. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Codename: Evita

AFAIK, the HTC One XL has the codename of Evita, and no other was attributed to this model.

The XL was introduced into the market just like the HTC One X, but with a significant improvement in communications:

> HTC One XL<sup>(TE)</sup>    4G Network (**LTE** 1800 / 2600)

<sup>PC World Australia article: [HTC One XL review: HTC's One X gets the superfast 4G treatment. Is the extra speed worth it?](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/mobile_phones/htc/one_xl/416591)</sup>

## Phone Information

1. About the Phone:

   To check you device's information, you can go to "Settings" and select "About Phone":

   [image: Android 4.0 ICS - About Phone]

   If the codename is presented, you should find it on the information provided there.
2. Accessing the configuration file:

   You can use a file manager and navigate to `/system/` and open the `build.prop` file, that contains all the details about your system.

   Locate the lines that start by `ro.product` to know your device's model; brand; codename; CPU and manufacturer (among others).

---

## References:

- [PDADB.net Search results for "HTC One" that include the devide codename](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdamaster&posted=1&model=HTC%20ONE&num_rows_max=0)
- [GSM Arena - HTC One XL: Full phone specifications](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_xl-4572.php)
- [geekaphone.com - HTC One XL Specifications](http://geekaphone.com/phones/HTC-One-XL-specs)
- [HTC Smartphones: HTC One XL](http://www.htc.com/asia/smartphones/htc-one-xl/)
- [Wikipedia: HTC One XL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_One_X#One_XL)